# Efficiently sort a disordered "subset" array based on the order of an already sorted "master" array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays of IDs. One is an unfiltered `master` array that has been sorted based on values in a separate `dataset` object, whose keys are are the aforementioned IDs). The other array is a `filtered` subset of `master`, which is sorted in the same way as `master`. Like so:

```
const dataset = {a: {...}, b: {...}, c: {...}, d: {...}, e: {...}, f: {...}, g: {...}}
const master = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
const filtered = ['a', 'c', 'd']
```

However, sometimes, the sort criteria changes, so I re-sort the `master` array. I **could** then re-filter this newly sorted master array in order to get my `filtered` array, but what I would *rather* do is just sort the `filtered` array based on the new order of the `master` array, as I assume this would be more efficient than running my filters again.

However, I'm not sure how to do it. For clarity, I *think* I want a flow something like this:

```
const mySort = (unsortedSubset, blueprint) => {
    // do sort here
}
const dataset = {a: {...}, b: {...}, c: {...}, d: {...}, e: {...}, f: 
const master = ['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
const filtered = ['a', 'c', 'd']

const sortedFiltered = mySort(filtered, master)
console.log(sortedFiltered)
// ['d', 'c', 'a']
```

Comment: How large are these arrays? Unless they're very large you're probably better off just sorting both using the normal method to avoid confusing code for some future maintainer (which could be you)

Comment: @PeterVanDrunen These arrays are large and are being sorted and filtered frequently. The issue is that in order to sort/filter, you first need to map the values in master to the dataset. In order to sort the filtered subset, you would need to map all those values to the ones in dataset as well, which would be inefficient in terms of both time and memory footprint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter the master array by using the filtered array for lookup.

```js
const
    mySort = (subset, blueprint) => blueprint.filter(v => subset.includes(v));
    dataset = { e: {}, d: {}, c: {}, b: {}, a: {} },
    master = ['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a'],
    filtered = ['a', 'c', 'd'],
    sortedFiltered = mySort(filtered, master);

console.log(sortedFiltered);
```

A version with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

```js
const
    mySort = (subset, blueprint) => blueprint.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(subset));
    dataset = { e: {}, d: {}, c: {}, b: {}, a: {} },
    master = ['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a'],
    filtered = ['a', 'c', 'd'],
    sortedFiltered = mySort(filtered, master);

console.log(sortedFiltered);
```

Comment: What is the benefit of the `Set` method?

Comment: it supplies a faster access for checking.